# JavaFX 8 TextArea: Select a substring and scroll to it

Tags: scroll, textarea, javafx-8, caret

I wish to search a `TextArea` for some substring and, if its found, to select and scroll to it's position.

The search is not the issue, neither is the selection. What's troubling me is the `TextArea` scrolling.

I've tried so far:

```
TextArea.caretPosition(int)/ TextArea.selectPositionCaret(int);

TextArea.caretPosition(int) / TextArea.extendSelection(int);

TextArea.selectRange(int, int)
```

But none of them seems to scrolls the `TextArea` to the so selected text.

Any hints?

Comment: tks @muraleekrishna for the formatting help :)

Answer (score 1):

I've just found my mistake...

The TextArea control must have the focus prior the selection changes.

All it's need:

```
TextArea.requestFocus();
TextArea.selectRange(int, int);
```